# Regular expression for only 2 letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to create regular expression for 2 and only 2 letters. I understood it has to be the following `/[a-z]{2}/i`, but it matches any string with 2 or more letters. Here is what I get:

```
my_reg_exp = /[a-z]{2}/i
my_reg_exp.match('aa')    # => #<MatchData "aa">
my_reg_exp.match('AA')    # => #<MatchData "AA">
my_reg_exp.match('a')     # => nil
my_reg_exp.match('aaa')   # => #<MatchData "aa">
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If "it has to be the following /[a-z]{2}/i", then it has to be that. What else could it be?

Comment: Can you have more than one word in a string? Do you want to find all two-letter words in such a string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add the anchors like this:

```
my_reg_exp = /^[a-z]{2}$/i
```

Test:

```
my_reg_exp.match('aaa')
#=> nil
my_reg_exp.match('aa')
#=> #<MatchData "aa">
```

Answer (score 2):

Hao's solution matches isn't locale sensitive. If this is important for your use case:

```
/\a[[:alpha:]]{2}\z/

2.0.0-p451 :005 > 'aba' =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\Z/
 => nil 
2.0.0-p451 :006 > 'ab' =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\Z/
 => 0 
2.0.0-p451 :007 > 'xy' =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\Z/
 => 0 
2.0.0-p451 :008 > 'zxy' =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\Z/
 => nil
```

Per usual, if you need further assistance, leave a comment.

Comment: I agree that your regex is better than Hao's, but it is wrong that Hao's regex only matches lowercase.

Comment: I think you want `\z` not `\Z`, because with `\Z` you would match e.g. `"ab\n"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/\b[a-z]{2}\b/i` to match a two-letter string. `/b`  Matches a word-break.

This means you can `scan` a string to find all occurrences:

```
'Foo is a bar'.scan(/\b[a-z]{2}\b/i) #=> ["is"]
```

Or find the first match in a string using:

```
'a bc def'[/\b[a-z]{2}\b/i] # => "bc"
```